# How to convert decimal date format (e.g. 2011.580) to normal date format?

Tags: r, date-formatting

I'm trying to change from the decimal date format (return type of cpts.ts() from the changepoint package) to the normal date format %Y-%m-%d. Example:

```
cpts.ts(myTimeSeries.BinSeg)
[1] 2001.667 2004.083 2008.750 2011.583 2011.917
```

The actual dates are sometime around August 2001, January 2004, September 2008, June/July 2011 and December 2011 (I don't know them exactly, I'm reading them off a graph).

I can't seem to find a standard method of converting this format back to the usual date format.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Slightly different results with `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
decimals <- c(2001.667, 2004.083, 2008.750, 2011.583, 2011.917)

format(date_decimal(decimals), "%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] "2001-09-01" "2004-01-31" "2008-10-01" "2011-08-01" "2011-12-01"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
> foo <- c(2001.667,2004.083,2008.750,2011.583,2011.917)
> as.Date(paste(trunc(foo),round((foo-trunc(foo))*365,0)),"%Y %j")
[1] "2001-08-31" "2004-01-30" "2008-09-30" "2011-08-01" "2011-12-01"
```

Look at `?as.Date` and its `format` parameter, which will direct you to `?strptime`, from which I took the `%j` format specification.

You may need to adapt for some corner cases, like January 1st.

Comment: You're right, this method doesn't handle January first - it just returns `NA` whenever there is a first of January!

Answer (score 4):

For those considering a base R solution to this issue, the core of lubridate's `date_decimal` is essentially:

```
start <- as.POSIXct(paste0(trunc(foo),  "/01/01"), tz="UTC") 
end   <- as.POSIXct(paste0(trunc(foo)+1,"/01/01"), tz="UTC") 
start + (difftime(end, start, units="secs") * (foo - trunc(foo)))
```

I.e. - set a `start` date back at the start of the year in which the date occurs, set an `end` date at the start of the following year, multiply the difference between start and end by the fraction of the year elapsed, add this difference back to the start. Doing this takes into account leap years, and will work appropriately for January 1st.