# Convert double to date format

Tags: r, date, zoo

I have a list of double that I want to convert to date of any format possible.

```
time = seq(2008,2017,length.out = 300)
```

I cannot use `as.Date(time)` directly cause the results will be starting from 1970.

Comment: Relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965699/converting-date-in-year-decimal-form-in-r and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29697436/how-to-convert-decimal-date-format-e-g-2011-580-to-normal-date-format/32468790

Answer (score 1):

Invert the order: **first** convert the start and end point to dates, **then** use `seq` to interpolate between them.

Using the ‹lubridate› package:

```
seq(ymd('2008-01-01'), ymd('2017-01-01'), length.out = 300)
```

(This is using the first of January as the start and end date; in your code it’s ambiguous what you wanted to use, and indeed one good reason why it can’t work like that.)